# Bit-Map vs ALOHA protocol

Tags: protocol, network, networking

So i have been reading about ALOHA and Bit-Map protocols and i am note sure which is more preferable in the following scenario:

8 stations, numbered 0-7 want to transmit in any given time slot. knowing that the contending time lasts t seconds, and the length of each broadcasting fame is 20t seconds.

what is the utilization of the channel and does the ALOHA protocol more efficient in this scenario?

because each station wants to broadcast in each time slot, there would be a lot of possible collisions, so even though bit map is slower, i think it is more beneficial in the correct scenario because there would be a lot of possible collision if we were using ALOHA.

is it correct? was there anything else i've been missing?

Comment: Cross-posting is not allowed. You asked this question here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58601/is-it-right-to-choose-aloha-and-not-bit-map-in-this-case

Comment: read carefully, the questions i've asked are different: here, i asked if ALL stations where broadcasting in the same time, and there if there's a difference between a particular station's broadcasting and the effects of choosing ALOHA on that scenario. the questions are different, and i respect site rules and i did not cross post, as the information i am trying to study is different in each site

Comment: If this is a unique question, why not also post it on Network Engineering SE? It’s a far more suitable place.

Comment: i thought the same, but apparently they don't like questions about making changes to protocols or questions by students trying to learn network theory. i also wanted to see who could help me instead of bashing me or giving me bad reputation because i'm asking a question. i came to stack exchange to learn, and this is all i'm interested at

Comment: it sounds like they are a bunch of technicians who want to call themselves engineers :( `Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment.`

Comment: If it's not on topic here, try CS. https://cs.stackexchange.com/help `computer architecture, networks` is listed as on-topic.

Comment: thank you very much @Jasen

Answer (score 1):

> 8 stations, numbered 0-7 want to transmit in any given time slot

"They want to transmit in any given time slot" means they always have data; that's the worst-case scenario for ALOHA.

So, if you know that every station always wants to transmit, you can omit the bitmap completely; simply let the stations send in turn.

Comment: what is the calculation for the network usage in both cases though? i want to understand it not only theoretically, but also mathematically if possible

Comment: by network usage i meant utilization. editing my question to correct the terminology